# Implementing OAuth2 or OpenID Connect - is a tool needed?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'd like to implement OpenID Connect or OAuth2 protocol.
My question is - do I need a tool to implement this? I know there are a number of open source tools and they have to be implemented on both sides - IDP side and SP side, correct?
Is it common (and is it easy) to roll your own? I guess my question is - do people usually use a tool or do they usually code the OAuth flow by hand?  I have a Java application with a JS front end. 
Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977068/choosing-an-openid-connect-provider/44996998#44996998 check this answer

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't see this post before!  Seems like the answer is to go with a third party product.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes going with an existing product outweighs in-house solutions most of the time. I pointed it out since I wrote that answer. Good that it helped you.!